# PHP call function for each line exec()

Tags: php, shell

I want to get the filepath of all files in a specific directory. The problem is that the directory is very big (about 400GB). I tried to make recursive calls to read all directories and subdirectories and it works fine - but it is slow.
I got the idea that I call »find ...« with exec. 
When using the shell I can obtain an array of all files but I only have access to that array when the process finished. 
It would be great to have something to get the results while searching so I can store it in my database and other programms have access to it. I thougt of calling a function for every (or every n) results. 
Is something like that possible and how would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

To get the results while searching, use [popen — Opens process file pointer —](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) instead of [exec — Execute an external program](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Answer (score 0):

Did I read correctly that you are using exec to find all of the files?

A better way to do this would be using php its self, with some of the available features like the [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) and [RecursiveDirectorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

Personally, I think that using these is a better idea than using exec to run a command. That way you are not passing the handling off to another process when you can just do it within php.

I am unsure on being able to get usable data while you are creating the array though. You could possibly store each value of the array into a database, that way, each time a value is added to the array, the database is updated. You could then use the information from the database while the script is still running.